# C# - Running a control or form on a separate thread properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, flash

I'm making a program that will have multiple shockwave flash controls running at a time. 
Due to the nature of flash and it's performance, I can't have all the controls running on the same UI thread.

My though to get around this issue would be to create children forms, each of which with their own flash control, and run them on new threads. I did that via:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numClients; i++)
        {
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    FrmClient c = new FrmClient();
                    c.ShowDialog();
                }));
            clientThread.IsBackground = true;
            clientThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            clientThread.Start();
        }
```

However this set up is so unstable and hacky it's not even funny. Crossthread exceptions are thrown left and right.

I'm invoking the form to access its members properly, but form can't even access its own members without invoking, example:

```
public partial class FrmClient : Form
{

    public FrmClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += new FormShownEventHandler(Shown);
    }  

    void Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
         // ^ CrossThreadException

         this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
              { 
                   this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
              }));
         // Works
     }
 }
```

And simply closing the form using the Exit button causes a cross thread exception in the ShowDialog() function used in the first code snippet.

I need to know, is there any other way to achieve what I need? Ultimately, the flash controls need to be running on separate threads. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want multiple app domains...

Maybe this might help...

http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/make-a-really-dynamic-plugin-using-multiple-application-domains/